# FOSRestBundle PUT one to many relation

Tags: symfony, one-to-many, fosrestbundle

I am using FOSRestBundle to handle the API connections in my app, however I stuck with PUTting one to many relation, **I don't know, how JSON should be composed**.

Note that entire API works, so all the form constructions, mapping, etc is configured well.

Entity

```
...
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MemberTranslation", mappedBy="member")
 * @Expose
 */
private $translations;
...
```

Form

```
...
$builder
    ->add('publicBiography', 'text')
;
...
```

I am expecting (the construction of JSON to be) something like:

```
{
    "member": {
        "translations": [
            { "id": 1, "publicBiography": "This is english trans" },
            { "id": 2, "publicBiography": "To jest polskie tłum." },
        ]
    } 
}
```

I actually don't know if this make sense but would be nice if someone could help me out.

Comment: You are asking about forms, serialization to json and doctrine. Three very different topics. Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: I can get from entity Member translations by $member->getTranslations(). Translation is mapped one to many entity called MemberTranslation which has id and publicBiography.

Now, I want to via FOSRestBundle PUT new publicBiography text, so how it should be done?

This is how the scheme looks like when I do GET:

{ "user": { "name": "Hello World", "member": { "employmentDates": "2015-01-01", "translations": [ { "id": 1, "publicBiography": "English trans" }, { "id": 2, "publicTranslation": "Polish one" }  ] }  } }

I can PUT user entity, member entity, but I have troubles with translation entity